# Display Multple Uploaded Images on page with PHP

Tags: php

Okay, this is what I got so far, I'm able to upload one image and display it in a div, but I just cant seem to figure out how to do the same for loading multiple images. As in upload multiple images and display all uploaded images on screen. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Also: I kinda think I have to set a variable for

$_FILES['image']['name'][0]
$_FILES['image']['name'][1]
etc

and do a forloop to print it out? Correct me if I am wrong?

```
<?php
// prevent timezone warnings
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

// set the upload location
$UPLOADDIR = "tmp";

// if the form has been submitted then save and display the image(s)
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    // loop through the uploaded files
    foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value){
        $image_tmp = $value['tmp_name'];
        $image = $value['name'];
        $image_file = "{$UPLOADDIR}{$image}";

        // move the file to the permanent location
        if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$image_file)){
            echo <<<HEREDOC

<div style="float:left;margin-right:10px">
    <img src="{$image_file}" alt="file not found" /></br>
</div>

HEREDOC;
        }
        else{
            echo "<h1>image file upload failed, image too big after compression</h1>";
        }
    }
}
else{
    ?>

<form name='newad' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action=''>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='file' name='image'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name='Submit' type='submit' value='Upload image'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I' am not sure which CMS/Framework this is but If you change this line

**From**

```
<input type='file' name='image'>
```

**To**

```
<input type='file' name='image[]' multiple>
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I tried this is what I get...

Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\sandbox\array\part2.php on line 40 - which line 40 is  if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$image_file)){

Comment: I won't be able to help that much because its a long code. You can checkout this website http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1395 which also have video tutorial on this.

Answer (score 0):

How are multiple files, you must have two loops. Put a `foreach` inside a `for`.
I believe that is what you want. Make sure the `tmp` folder has write permission.

```
<?php
// prevent timezone warnings
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

// set the upload location
$UPLOADDIR = "tmp";

// if the form has been submitted then save and display the image(s)
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

    $num_files = count($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    for($x = 0; $x < $num_files; $x++){
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'][$x];
        $image_file = $UPLOADDIR."/". $image;
        if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$x])){
            $messages[] = '<h1>'.$image.' image file upload failed, image too big after compression</h1>."<br>"';
        }
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$x],$image_file)){
            echo '
            <div style="float:left;margin-right:10px">
                <img src="'.$image_file.'" alt="file" /></br>
            </div>';
        } else{
            echo "<h1>image file upload failed, image too big after compression</h1>";
        }
    }
}else {
    ?>

<form name='newad' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action=''>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='file' name='image[]'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='file' name='image[]'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name='Submit' type='submit' value='Upload image'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```